# M2 drive for Xiaomi air 13.3

Tags: ssd

I just bought a Xiaomi air 13.3 (2018). It comes with 2 M2 SSD bays, one is occupied by the stock M2 NVMe (that I replaced with a Samsung 970) and the other one is open.

I tried to put the old SSD in the empty slot, but it doesn't fit. I looked into it and I found that the second slot isn't an NVMe slot, but a mSATA or SATA i think. (I couldn't find the specification while googling).

Since I still have an empty SSD slot, I am looking for a drive between 500GB and 1TB to put into the laptop. The cheaper the drive is the better.

Comment: How much storage are you looking for? How much are you willing to spend?

Comment: I'm going for 500GB - 1TB, more storage is better.
The less i spend is better.

Answer (score 0):

After looking deeper into this, the second free M2 slot is SATA. The best choice is SATA M2 with B&M key like the Crucial MX500